# columns are not reading in sequential order while reading excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a excel sheet with data in 200 columns, to import in to DB i'm using
below code

```
private File upp;
InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(upp);
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

while(rows.hasNext()) { 
    String data="";
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
    if(row.getRowNum() == 0 || row.getRowNum() == 1) {
        Iterator rowCells = row.cellIterator();
        while(rowCells.hasNext()) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) rowCells.next();
            for(int i=0; i <= cell.getCellNum(); i++) {

            }             
            data = data + cell.getCellNum() + " ,";
        }
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    slrow++;
}
```

i'm excepting output to be

```
0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,
```

but the output is

```
0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,17 ,16 ,18 ,
```

its not reading in sequential order as expected I'm unable to find out where the mistake is in this code

Comment: Can you post the first 20 columns of the row that is giving you this issue?

Comment: Also, does the real version of the innermost loop do anything to missing cells, like fill them in? Because that might explain what is happening.

Comment: `HSSFCell.getCellNum()`is deprecated since a long time. Use `getColumnIndex()`.

Comment: Your code looks a little odd, what happens when you [simplify it and follow one of the Apache POI examples for iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no the innermost loop is doing nothing, i tried by removing that loop also

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is the rows what i'm trying to read it from excel col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17 col18 col19 col20 this data is in first row of excel sheet.

Comment: @AxelRichter getColumnIndex() is not supported by HSSFCell

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getColumnIndex()

Comment: Please post the columns as an update to your question, with formatting included. I am pretty sure that there is no issue with your code, just with the way the library handles your file combined with the way the file is written. You can get the right order by sorting after you read. Would you like me to post an answer about how to do that?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is by reading excel sheet columns i need to insert it in to DB but the order what its taking now is not in sequential so if insert this extracted data means this will mismatch with columns what i have in DB so i'm trying to get it in sequential order. Any how post your answer l will try with that.

Comment: and excel sheet extension is ".xlsx", whether is this is causing problem... i mean is this is right way to read excel sheet with .xlsx?

Answer (score -1):

Use JXL library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency
```

Code example

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);

            // TO get the access to the sheet. 
//For single sheet
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);

            // To get the number of rows present in sheet
            int totalNoOfRows = sheet.getRows();

            // To get the number of columns present in sheet
            int totalNoOfCols = sheet.getColumns();

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

                for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                    map.put(sheet.getCell(col, 0).getContents(),
                            sheet.getCell(col, row).getContents());

                }
            }
```

I hope this will be helpfull.

Comment: How do you know that will help? Is there some guarantee that this library will not have an issue in the same spot because of the way the file was written?